# Trait method which returns `Self`-type with a different type and/or lifetime parameter

Tags: rust

The Rust compiler doesn't allow specifying new type parameters on `Self` in the return types of trait methods.  That is, a trait method can return `Self`, but not `Self<T>`.  I'm interested in what the proper way is to accomplish the following; or if it's fundamentally impossible, then why that's the case.

Suppose we have two structs as follows:

```rust
pub struct SomeStruct<T> {
    id: usize,
    description: String,
    extra_data: T,
}

pub struct OtherStruct<T> {
    permit_needed: bool,
    registration_number: usize,
    extra_data: T,
}
```

Both of these structs have an `extra_data` field of type `T`, where `T` is a generic type parameter.  We can implement methods such as `get_extra_data()`, and more interestingly, `transform()`, on both structs:

```rust
impl<T> SomeStruct<T> {
    pub fn get_extra_data(&self) -> &T {
        &self.extra_data
    }

    pub fn transform<S>(&self, data: S) -> SomeStruct<S> {
        SomeStruct {
            id: self.id,
            description: self.description.clone(),
            extra_data: data,
        }
    }
}

impl<T> OtherStruct<T> {
    pub fn get_extra_data(&self) -> &T {
        &self.extra_data
    }

    pub fn transform<S>(&self, data: S) -> OtherStruct<S> {
        OtherStruct {
            permit_needed: self.permit_needed,
            registration_number: self.registration_number,
            extra_data: data,
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm having trouble creating a trait `Transformable` that unifies these two types with respect to these operations:

```rust
trait Transformable<T> {
    fn get_extra_data(&self) -> &T;
    fn transform<S>(&self, data: S) -> Self<S>;
}
```

The `transform()` function needs to return something of the same type as `Self`, just with a different type parameter.  Unfortunately, the rust compiler rejects this with the error message `E0109: type arguments are not allowed for this type`.

Even the weaker signature `fn transform<S>(&self, data: S) -> impl Transformable<S>` is rejected, with error `E0562: impl Trait not allowed outside of function and inherent method return types`. The traditional solution here, to my knowledge, would be to return an associated type instead of an `impl`, but that would require generic associated types in this case.  And at any rate that would seem much more roundabout than the stronger `Self<S>` signature which is what we really want.

[Playground link with the above code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b1d13b0a172119e90d59d026eef709b8)

An analogous problem happens exactly the same way with lifetime parameters.  I'm actually more interested in the lifetime parameters case, but I thought the type parameters case might be easier to understand and talk about, and also make it clear that the issue isn't lifetime-specific.

Comment: The number of generic arguments required by a struct is not known to the trait.

Comment: `fn transform<S>(&self, data: S) -> impl Transformable<S>;` would be pretty close to what you want. But `impl Trait` can't be used in trait definition yet. I'm not sure it will ever be supported either.

Comment: It's not possible to achieve this with `Self<T>`, `impl Transformable<S>`, `Box<dyn Transformable<S>>`, etc. I wrote quite a long answer and I discarded it, because you already know it.  What's wrong with associated types, like [this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=62db48fffbf995277d9dc7d763526a59)? Maybe you can elaborate more on the usage, how this is going to be used in the whole project and there can be another way how to achieve what you want?

Comment: If `Self` is a type that isn't generic, what on earth would `Self<S>` mean?

Comment: Thanks all for the comments noting that the trait doesn't know whether `Self` is generic - that makes total sense.  @zrzka I'm trying something related to your playground's solution.  Thanks for the suggestion.